# Ansible loop over list generated with Jinja2 template

Tags: python, list, ansible, jinja2

I'm using Ansible, and I need to loop over a list stored in a variable I get from a file (with include_vars).
Everything is fine, I can use the various values, except I don't manage to loop over the list.

Specifically, I can't do this:

```
---

- host: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ [1,2,3,4] }}"
```

It yells : "need a list, got: [1,2,3,4]"

but if I use

```
loop: [1,2,3,4]
```

Then it works

Can someone explain why it doesn't work ?

Extra info:
Ansible ver: 2.7.0rc2
Python: 3.9.2

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Ansible are you using? And you mentioned you need to "loop over a list stored in a variable I get from a file", but that's not what you're showing in your example; can you provide an example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: My version of ansible is 2.7.0rc2, python 3.9.2. The example above reproduce the problem. The error message is : "FAILED! => {"msg": "Invalid data passed to 'loop', it requires a list, got this instead: [1,2,3,4]. Hint: If you passed a list/dict of just one element, try adding wantlist=True to your lookup invocation or use query instead of lookup."}. In my 'real' problem, I just have a different dict printed in the error "got this instead: ["xxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxx",...]. But the problem remains the same : object returned by "{{ }}" is not a list

Comment: Now, with the full error message provided, the problem is more clear. You should edit your question and include the in your comment provided important information and may have a look into the answer(s).

Answer (score 1):

Because of the message

> `need a list, got: [1,2,3,4]`

which indicates a [variable type mismatch](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#list-variables), you may introduce the [`type_debug` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-data-types)

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

   LIST: [1, 2, 3, 4]

  tasks:

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }} of {{ item | type_debug }}"
    loop: "{{ LIST }}"
```

and other options for debugging, in example [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item | type_debug }}"
    loop: "{{ [1,2,3,4] }}"
    loop_control:
      extended: true
      label: "{{ item }}"
```

Since this second, your example is working properly in Ansible 2.9.25, resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] ***********
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) =>
  msg: int
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) =>
  msg: int
ok: [localhost] => (item=3) =>
  msg: int
ok: [localhost] => (item=4) =>
  msg: int
```

it brings up the question, which version of Ansible you are using?

The issue can be reproduced by

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: no
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item | type_debug }}"
    loop: "[1,2,3,4]"
```

resulting into an output of

```
TASK [Show result] ***********
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: 'Invalid data passed to ''loop'', it requires a list, got this instead: [1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: I use Ansible 2.7.0, it may be the cause of the issue, the example I give above doesn't work for me.

Comment: The examples given here in the answer are working at least as of Ansible v2.9.